# Автоматизация верстки

Tags: photoshop, html, вёрстка

Пользуетесь ли вы автоматизацией верстки?
Если да то какими?

Comment: Стараюсь быстро печатать, разрабатываю пальцы.

Comment: Что вы конкретно понимаете под "автоматизацией вёрстки"?

Comment: PSD to HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В фотошопе можно быстро нарезать и сверстать кусками табличный макет, а потом перегнать конвертером в div'ы, чтобы уж совсем комильфо было. А если серьёзно - того, чего вы ищите пока нет, или уж совсем убого всё на выходе получается (ну или я не натыкался на сие произведение искусства).

Comment: Слыхал, некоторые умельцы пользуют [Adobe Fireworks][1]. Но, конечно, без напильника и тут не обойтись. Ручная работа всегда была в моде.


  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Fireworks

Comment: Да просто спросил потому что услышал про верстальщиков которые макет за 10 минут верстают .....

Comment: Ложь.Все зависит от сложности макета и качества исполнения.

Comment: Ага, а еще есть сертифицированные битриксом мастера, которые за 10 минут мышкой макет в веб-форме составляют. Потом все с нуля переделывать приходится.

Comment: =) я уж подумал что я тормоз)))